# Kotlin Voice Recognition in Spanish

Tags: android, kotlin, speech-to-text, voice-recognition

I want to make a Voice Recognition App in Kotlin. When I sets "en-US" language, everything works fine, but when I sets "es-ES", the voice recognition never ends.
onPartialResults give me some results when I speaking, but onResults is never called, and the recognition never ends. Only if I sets "es-ES". If I sets "en-US", onResults is called and recognize perfectly.
I have downloaded en-US language, and es-ES language, for offline recognition in my config.

Whats happens? I need help

My code:

```
val language = "es-ES" //"en-US"
val speech: SpeechRecognizer = SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(activity)
speech.setRecognitionListener(this)
intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, language)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_ONLY_RETURN_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE, language)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PARTIAL_RESULTS, true)
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, 2)
speech.startListening(intent)
```

Thanks

Comment: I tried you code, but I didn't receive the exception you mentioned.

Comment: @shirley I have a Xiaomi Redmi Note 7. The problem will it be some configuration?